# How to find the configuration differences between two identical usb audio dongle devices?

Tags: drivers, usb, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I have two units of the same headset model that use a wireless USB dongle (Logitech H800). Each headset only pairs with its own dongle, but I want to get the same dongle to work with both headsets.

How can I find out what the "configuration" differences are on the Linux driver's side for these two devices to see if there is something I can change to make dongle 1 switch between being paired with headset 1 and with headset 2?

*Background:*

- Logitech provides a pairing utility for Mac/ Windows. I do not know if the utility changes a local configuration setting or a setting on the headset itself, so I am exploring to see if a local change is enough.
- I realize the headsets can use Bluetooth, but I prefer the dongle.

*More Info:*

**system:** Kubuntu 15.04

**audio stack:** ALSA, PulseAudio, GStreamer

**dmesg:**

```
$ dmesg | tail -n 100| grep input
[32566.401792] input: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.3/0003:046D:0A29.0006/input/input19
[32566.454789] hid-generic 0003:046D:0A29.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input3
[32572.041443] input: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3/0003:046D:0A29.0007/input/input20
[32572.095904] hid-generic 0003:046D:0A29.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input3
```

**arecord/ aplay:**

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Headset [Logitech Wireless Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Headset_1 [Logitech Wireless Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Headset [Logitech Wireless Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Headset_1 [Logitech Wireless Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**lshw:**

```
             *-usb:0
                  description: Audio device
                  product: Logitech Wireless Headset
                  vendor: Logitech
                  physical id: 1
                  bus info: usb@1:1.1
                  version: 76.57
                  serial: 000D44D4F293
                  capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
                  configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=144mA speed=12Mbit/s
             *-usb:1
                  description: Audio device
                  product: Logitech Wireless Headset
                  vendor: Logitech
                  physical id: 2
                  bus info: usb@1:1.2
                  version: 76.57
                  serial: 000D44D3C120
                  capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
                  configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=144mA speed=12Mbit/s
```